# Spotify Status from user's presence using discord.js v14

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

so I was trying to get Spotify Current Playing details from users' activity using discord.js

The thing is, it always returns "You're not playing anything right now" even when I'm playing a track from Spotify.

Here's my code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const { CustomRGB } = require("discordjs-colors-bundle");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('spotify')
    .setDescription('Spotify informations!')
    .addSubcommand((sub) => 
      sub.setName('current').setDescription('Get your current playing status')
    ),

  async execute(interaction, client) {
    if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() == "current") {
      const member = interaction.member;

      const Embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle(`${interaction.user.username}'s current playing status`);

      if ( member.presence.activities[0].name != "spotify") {
        Embed.setColor(CustomRGB(255, 0, 0));
        Embed.setDescription("User is not playing anything right now.");
      } else {
        const activity = member.presence.activities[0];
        Embed.addFields(
          { name: "Track Name", value: `${activity.details}`, inline: true },
          { name: "Artist Name", value: `${activity.state}`, inline: true }
        );
        Embed.setColor(CustomRGB(0, 255, 170));
      }

      return interaction.reply({ embeds: [Embed], ephemeral: true });
    }
  },
};
```

I was expecting to get the current Spotify playing track name and artist name from the activity.

Comment: Voted to close as it's a simple typo. `name != "spotify"` should be `name != "Spotify"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code checks if the activity name is `spotify`.

#### Fix:

```js
// ...
if (member.presence.activities[0].name != "Spotify") {
// ...
```

If you take a look at the presence activity structure, this is what it looks like:

```js
Activity {
  name: 'Spotify',
  type: 2,
  url: null,
  details: 'Some Song',
  state: 'Author 1; Author 2',
  applicationId: null,
  timestamps: { start: 2023-07-08T14:04:32.776Z, end: 2023-07-08T14:08:07.175Z },
  party: { id: 'spotify:838620835282812969' },
  assets: RichPresenceAssets {
    largeText: 'Song',
    smallText: null,
    largeImage: 'spotify:ab1234',
    smallImage: null
  },
  flags: ActivityFlagsBitField { bitfield: 48 },
  emoji: null,
  buttons: [],
  createdTimestamp: 1688825073865
}
```

I recommend checking if the user has a presence first, so that you don't run into further errors.